# Can you input multiple fields into arrays in a JOption pane input?

Tags: java, arrays, joptionpane

I am trying to create a multiple array setup where I have book authors, titles and page counts all input from one JOption panel, and the newly filled arrays would be used as source for a single book array setup.  This is the code I have atm, is this even possible?  I can get to the pane to input, but immediately get an error after entering data (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous ctor sym type: 
    at librarybook.LibraryBookSorting.main(LibraryBookSorting.java:43)
~\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1)

The code I am currently starting is this :

```
public class LibraryBookSorting {

static LibraryBook[] myBook = new LibraryBook[5];
static String title[5];
static String author[5];
static String count[5];
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        JTextField Title = new JTextField(5);
        JTextField Author = new JTextField(5);
        JTextField pgCount = new JTextField(5);

        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
        myPanel.add(new JLabel("Title:"));
        myPanel.add(Title);
        myPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15)); // a spacer
        myPanel.add(new JLabel("Author:"));
        myPanel.add(Author);
        myPanel.add(new JLabel("PageCount: "));
        myPanel.add(pgCount);
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel,
                "Please Enter Title, Author and Page Count.",
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        title[i] = Title.getText();
        author[i] = Author.getText();
        count[i] = pgCount.getText();

        myBook[0] = new LibraryBook(title[0], author[0], count[0]);
        myBook[1] = new LibraryBook(title[1], author[1], count[1]);
        myBook[2] = new LibraryBook(title[2], author[2], count[2]);
        myBook[3] = new LibraryBook(title[3], author[3], count[3]);
        myBook[4] = new LibraryBook(title[4], author[4], count[4]);

        for (int i = 0; i < myBook.length; i++) {
            myBook.toString();
        }
    }

}
```

My book class is

```
public class LibraryBook {

    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String pageCount;

    //no arg contructor
    public LibraryBook() {
        title = "";
        author = "";
        pageCount = "";
    }

    public LibraryBook(String bookTitle, String bookAuthor, String bookpageCount) {
        title = bookTitle;
        author = bookAuthor;
        pageCount = bookpageCount;
    }

    //get methods
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getPageCount() {
        return pageCount;
    }
    //set methods

    public void setTitle(String bookTitle) {
        title = bookTitle;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String bookAuthor) {
        author = bookAuthor;
    }

    public void setPageCount(String bookPageCount) {
        pageCount = bookPageCount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("Your book is: " + title + " by " + author + " with " + pageCount + " pages.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation so the code you show is readable. also, show the actual code. the code you show is not compilable (for example, your main() method refers to a variable named "count", but there is no such variable declared in the code).

Answer (score 0):

Your **LibraryBookSorting** class has many errors like wrong declaration of arrays and **i** is being used two tomes for two different loops, once those errors are fixed your code is working perfectly. Have a look at below code :

```
public class LibraryBookSorting {

    static LibraryBook[] myBook = new LibraryBook[5];
    static String title[] = new String[5];
    static String author[] = new String[5];
    static String count[] = new String[5];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            JTextField Title = new JTextField(5);
            JTextField Author = new JTextField(5);
            JTextField pgCount = new JTextField(5);

            JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
            myPanel.add(new JLabel("Title:"));
            myPanel.add(Title);
            myPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15)); // a spacer
            myPanel.add(new JLabel("Author:"));
            myPanel.add(Author);
            myPanel.add(new JLabel("PageCount: "));
            myPanel.add(pgCount);
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel,
                    "Please Enter Title, Author and Page Count.",
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            title[i] = Title.getText();
            author[i] = Author.getText();
            count[i] = pgCount.getText();

            myBook[0] = new LibraryBook(title[0], author[0], count[0]);
            myBook[1] = new LibraryBook(title[1], author[1], count[1]);
            myBook[2] = new LibraryBook(title[2], author[2], count[2]);
            myBook[3] = new LibraryBook(title[3], author[3], count[3]);
            myBook[4] = new LibraryBook(title[4], author[4], count[4]);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < myBook.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(myBook[j].toString());
        }

    }
}
```